# C++ class syntax mistakes: access specifiers and nonstatic declarations in .cpp file

Tags: c++

This is the header file (no error here):

```
#ifndef BIOM_H
#define BIOM_H
#include <string>
class Biom {
public:
    Biom();
    ~Biom();
    std::string name;
};
#endif
```

And this is the C++ file (error in line 4):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Biom.h"

public:
Biom::Biom() {}
Biom::~Biom() {}
std::string Biom::name;
```

Comment: public/private/protected can only be used (and only means something) when doing declarations. Also, You don't need to define your 'name' variable in the CPP file. It is not static.

Comment: You only need `std::string Biom::name;` outside of the class when that member is `static`

Comment: Get rid of `public:` from the cpp file.  You only use it declarations, not definitions.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @AlexG, nope, they can only be used in _declarations_, and one can put them in `.cpp` files as well.

Comment: @ForceBru updated. I didn't think of structs declared in cpp files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct C++ file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Biom.h"

Biom::Biom() {}
Biom::~Biom() {}
```

I could have omitted the constructor and destructor and let it be default generated. Then I wouldn't need the .cpp file at all.